# File opened with XLConnect doesn't close

Tags: r, excel, xlconnect

I am working on an excel file with several sheets:

```
path_metadata<- file.path("archivos", "metadatos", "metadatos-copia.xlsx")
metadata_wb <- loadWorkbook(path_metadata)
```

Then I do some sheet manipulation (e.g. I write a data frame on a sheet), so I write it:

```
writeWorksheet(metadata_wb, df, sheet = "metadata")
```

And apply some style I have previously worked out

```
setCellStyle(metadata_wb,
             formula = rango_header_1,
             cellstyle = style_header)
```

And lastly, I save it

```
saveWorkbook(metadata_wb)
```

The problem comes when I try then to move onto the excel file and modify and save anything on it, it reports I cannot do it, because another instance keeps the file open.
I cannot do a `close(metadata_wb)` with an object of class `workbook`
What am I missing?

Thanx

Comment: From which package is loadWorkbook? Does it provide another function to close the connection to the file? What does the help page of loadWorkbook say about closing documents?

Comment: The package is XLConnect. It doesn't provide a close function. On the vignette, it reads that loading, writting, saving allows you to open and close it. (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XLConnect/vignettes/XLConnect.pdf).

Comment: This is a known bug on windows, it has been reported as an issue but nothing new yet